# replacing numpy array values in-place for arrays with custom dtype

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have data that looks like the following:

```
x = np.array([('joe', [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 3, 2, 4]),\
              ('sally', [7, 3, 5, 1, 4, 3, 2, 4])],\
              dtype=np.dtype([('name', 'a10'), ('scores', (float, 8))]))
```

and I want to replace values in the 'scores' column with something like the result from `np.maximum.accumulate()`. If I had a numpy array y with values:

```
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 3, 2, 4]
```

I get output like:

```
[1 3 5 7 9 9 9 9]
```

but I can't seem to get this to work on numpy arrays that have complex or custom data types. I assume this has something to do with creating views vs. copies of the data, but I can't seem to figure it out.

I've tried several different methods:

```
x['scores'] = np.maximum.accumulate(x['scores'])
```

and

```
for i, score in enumerate(x):
   x[i]['scores'] = np.maximum.accumulate(x[i]['scores'])
```

but neither seem to be able to replace the values in place. Any suggestions for how I can accomplish this would be greatly appreciate. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not the assignment, it's `np.maximum.accumulate` which isn't returning what you think:

```
>>> np.maximum.accumulate(x["scores"])
array([[ 1.,  3.,  5.,  7.,  9.,  3.,  2.,  4.],
       [ 7.,  3.,  5.,  7.,  9.,  3.,  2.,  4.]])
```

If you specify `axis=1`, though:

```
>>> np.maximum.accumulate(x["scores"], axis=1)
array([[ 1.,  3.,  5.,  7.,  9.,  9.,  9.,  9.],
       [ 7.,  7.,  7.,  7.,  7.,  7.,  7.,  7.]])
>>> x["scores"] = np.maximum.accumulate(x["scores"], axis=1)
>>> x
array([('joe', [1.0, 3.0, 5.0, 7.0, 9.0, 9.0, 9.0, 9.0]),
       ('sally', [7.0, 7.0, 7.0, 7.0, 7.0, 7.0, 7.0, 7.0])], 
      dtype=[('name', 'S10'), ('scores', '<f8', (8,))])
```

---

PS: when you're working with named columns, using [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org) makes life much more convenient than bare `numpy`, and I recommend it heartily.

Comment: Thank you! I was so very confused as to why none of the assignment methods I was trying were working. Is it actually doing anything in the default `axis = 0` case then?

Comment: @notlink: yep, it's taking the maximum along `axis=0`. :^)  Compare `[7,3,5,7,9,3,2,4]` with `[7,3,5,1,4,3,2,4]`.